# Reset value from sharedPreferences

Tags: save, sharedpreferences, setvalue

My app has a lot of classes and i save the score into sharePref individually.Every class has its own sharePref.In the end i made a class that i sum all these sharePref into an integer named totalscore ,something like this https://gyazo.com/3f0f9da2c64e587dd6244cf3933f957c .Eventually it works.

I want to clear the values of sharePreferences when i press the restart button because it keeps the high score.

Thank you for your time and sorry for my Engish.

Comment: The question isn't clear can you elaborate it more and one more thing avoid adding your code as image

Comment: Thank your for your time.I edit my question,hope to be more clear.Could you help me ?

Comment: So you want to clear all sharedPreferences or just one specific one?

Comment: All of them.I put all the Sharepreferences keys into totalscore and i tried to set totalscore to 0 but it doesnt work obviously.

Comment: Check my answer and tell me if you have any problems implementing it.

Comment: i saw it thank you very much.i will try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way usually I manage `sharedPreferences` in my projects is that, I create a class named `AppPreferences` and then create getters and setters methods in it for reading and writing some preferences. This helps me manage all the preferences also all user preferences are at one place.

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class AppPreferences {
 private static AppPreferences mAppPreferences;
 protected Context mContext;
 private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
 private SharedPreferences.Editor mSharedPreferencesEditor;

 private AppPreferences(Context context) {
  mContext = context;
  mSharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("AppPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  mSharedPreferencesEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
 }

 /**
  * Creates single instance of AppPreferences
  *
  * @param context - context of Activity or Service
  * @return Returns instance of Class AppPreferences
  */
 public static synchronized AppPreferences getInstance(Context context) {

  if (mAppPreferences == null) {
   mAppPreferences = new AppPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
  }
  return mAppPreferences;
 }

 /**
  * Stores String value in preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param value - value for that key
  */
 public void setValue(String key, String value) {
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.putString(key, value);
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
 }

 /**
  * Stores int value in preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param value - value for that key
  */
 public void setValue(String key, int value) {
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.putInt(key, value);
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
 }

 /**
  * Stores Double value in String format in preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param value - value for that key
  */
 public void setValue(String key, double value) {
  setValue(key, Double.toString(value));
 }

 /**
  * Stores long value in preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param value - value for that key
  */
 public void setValue(String key, long value) {
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.putLong(key, value);
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
 }

 /**
  * Stores boolean value in preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param value - value for that key
  */
 public void setValue(String key, boolean value) {
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.putBoolean(key, value);
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves String value from preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param defaultValue - default value if no key found
  */
 public String getStringValue(String key, String defaultValue) {
  return mSharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves int value from preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param defaultValue - default value if no key found
  */
 public int getIntValue(String key, int defaultValue) {
  return mSharedPreferences.getInt(key, defaultValue);
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves long value from preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference
  * @param defaultValue - default value if no key found
  */
 public long getLongValue(String key, long defaultValue) {
  return mSharedPreferences.getLong(key, defaultValue);
 }

 /**
  * Retrieves boolean value from preference
  *
  * @param keyFlag - key of preference
  * @param defaultValue default value if no key found
  */
 public boolean getBoolanValue(String keyFlag, boolean defaultValue) {
  return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(keyFlag, defaultValue);
 }

 /**
  * Removes key from preference
  *
  * @param key - key of preference that is to be deleted
  */
 public void removeKey(String key) {
  if (mSharedPreferencesEditor != null) {
   mSharedPreferencesEditor.remove(key);
   mSharedPreferencesEditor.commit();
  }
 }


 /**
  * Clears all the preferences stored
  */
 public void clear() {
  mSharedPreferencesEditor.clear().commit();
 }
}
```

Now you can use the above example anywhere in your project and when you want to remove something just call `removeKey` function and pass the key.

**SIDE NOTE:** Create a Constants.java file in your project and add all the keys and static variables in it, that way you don't have to worry about keys spellings and all.